# Bus ticket transfer in Ingolstadt, Germany?

Tags: transit, public-transport, europe, germany, buses

On Monday I am planning to use two buses (16 and 30) in Ingolstadt, Germany, and I am not going to waste a minute between the transition.

I know I can buy a ticket from the bus driver. So, can I use the ticket I used in the first bus into the second one too, or do I need to buy a new ticket on the second bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at the Ingolstadt transit agency's website shows that they have zone fares. That means that you would buy a ticket for that amount of zones. A one-way will allow you to travel the whole route in the same direction; the validity is 2 or 3 hours, allowing for changes and interruptions.

You most likely will not have to show the ticket when you get on the second bus.

Comment: Just make sure you ask for a ticket to your final destination and not to the stop where you're planning to change buses. Otherwise, your ticket might or might not be valid for the entire trip, depending on where exactly the stops are located.

Comment: @Sabine: Good comment, could be crucial for people not used to zone fares and Tarifverbünde, where operators work together instead of competing against each other…